# Wordpress can't echo brackets

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple plugin that will output the URL and title of a post. It should look like this:

http://mysite.com/test-2/{Test 2}

However when I use the code that I posted below, it prints as follows:

http://mysite.com/test-2/Test 2

{}

I can't figure out why. I've tried to escape them, separating each bracket into a string and combining them, but nothing seems to work.

Heres the code

```
function P2S_menu(){
    echo '<h1>This is a Test</h1>';

    $query = new WP_Query($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1');
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        $url = the_permalink();
        $keyword = the_title();
        Print('<p>' . $url . '&#123;' . $keyword . '&#125;' . '</p><br>');
    }
    echo 'Done';

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The functions `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` print their results by default. Use `get_permalink()` and `get_the_title()` instead:

```
while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();
    $url = get_permalink();
    $keyword = get_the_title();
    Print('<p>' . $url . '&#123;' . $keyword . '&#125;' . '</p><br>');
}
```

Comment: @user849170: Mark the answer as accepted to let others know that the issue is resolved.